# How to add (copy and paste) existing typescript and other necessary files from an existing project to a new project made with angular-cli?

Tags: angular, typescript, copy-paste, angular-cli

I have a project under development and would like to use angular-cli to continue development. The problem is that the angular-cli only recognizes errors in components that were created with 'ng g component name' and lets you pass the errors of the components copied from the old project. I already researched a lot, including here in stackoverflow, I found someone suggesting using 'ng init' but this only gives me an option to overwrite existing files but still can not identify the errors of the components copied from the previous project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I started using angular-cli a little while ago and realized that the reason he was not finding the error in the files I copied from the old project was because I was not importing them and referencing them on some component or module that was directly or indirectly connected to the app.module. I imagine that because the tree shake occurs when I use 'ng serve' it does not even bother to look for error in files that will not be used. Thank you to anyone who tried to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `ng init` command that will initialise with angular-cli your current project.

Do it carefully, as it will try to modify and add a lot of files, but before any file is modified you will be able to see the diff it generates with the original one so you can add the ng-cli contents manually, and discard them in the cli process.